# Navmesh string pulling vs funneling

Tags: path-finding

I'm creating a path-finder for navmesh. I'm wondering which method should I use after the A* has been completed, funneling or string pulling? What are the advantages/disadvantages of using them on a triangle-based navmesh?

Comment: I might be completely wrong here since I looked both these algorithms up the other day, but aren't they essentially one and the same thing?

Comment: @Ray Dey, both can be used to accomplish path refining in a mesh after the path-find has been executed.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was WHEN I looked both these algorithms up, they seemed to point to the same resources (on Google anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stopping condition for the funneling algorithm is the invalidity of the cone I think you'll get pretty much the same end result than with string pulling.

But using another stopping condition you can produce more various behaviors by setting a particular aperture threshold and/or by tweaking how the local target/velocity is chosen in the final cone.